# rmsdB value onRmsChanged in RecognitionListener is not going higer than 10.0

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech, recognizer-intent

my work for recognize sound is going well.

but what I need is not just recognize but also measure decibel of sound.

but onRmsChanged in RecognitionListener is not getting the value higher than 10.0

how can I get higher value from RecognitionListener? is it possible?

or should I use the other things?

please help me..

thanks!

below my my code, but nothing special.

```
  private RecognitionListener listener = new RecognitionListener() {

    @Override public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        if(decibel < rmsdB) decibel = rmsdB;
        Log.v(TAG+"2","onRmsChanged :" + rmsdB);
    }
```